# ScrollTop Javascript is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am having an issue with my nav bar not working correctly with the ScrollTop Javascript. It works in Chrome and Safari but not Firefox.

This is all the code I currently have on the site. I want the nav bar to follow the scroll once the nav bar is at the top of the page. Please view in Firefox as that is where I am having the issue!

Html

```
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <nav class="bottom" id="nav">
      <div class="buttonWrapper">
        <a href="#about">
          <div class="navButton">About</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#designs">
          <div class="navButton">Designs</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#contact">
          <div class="navButton">Contact</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="largeLogo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container about" id="about">
    <div class="sideBar about">
      <div class="sidebarText"></div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container designs" id="designs">
    <div class="view view-ninth">
      <img src="images/11.jpg" />
      <div class="mask mask-1"></div>
      <div class="mask mask-2"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Hover Style #9</h2>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBar designs">
      <div class="sidebarText"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container contact" id="contact">
    <div class="sideBar contact">
      <div class="sidebarText"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});

window.addEventListener("scroll", navTop, false);

function navTop() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
  var about = document.getElementById("about").offsetTop - 1;
  if (document.body.scrollTop > about) {
    nav.className = "minimize";
  } else {
    nav.className = "bottom";
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnbq36xf/1/)

Comment: are you check console in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `document.body.scrollTop`. Try using below code :

```
function navTop() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
  var about = document.getElementById("about").offsetTop - 1;
  var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop > about) {
    nav.className = "minimize";
  } else {
    nav.className = "bottom";
  }
}
```

`$(document).scrollTop();` / `$(window).scrollTop();` works for both Firefox and Chrome